# Column Update Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the data in the following format:

```
Tran No   Date        Store ID   Register ID  Tender
  01      23-10-2015    1000        001        CASH
  01      23-10-2015    1000        001        CRDT
  02      23-10-2015    1000        001        CASH
  02      23-10-2015    1000        001        GIFT
```

A new column has been added (Tran Seq) to the table

Such that the new data would become like

```
Tran No   Date        Store ID   Register ID  Tender   Tran Seq   
  01      23-10-2015    1000        001        CASH       0
  01      23-10-2015    1000        001        CRDT       1
  02      23-10-2015    1000        001        CASH       0
  02      23-10-2015    1000        001        GIFT       1
```

For every same TRAN NO, DATE, STORE ID and REGISTER ID, each line item would get a new sequence number in the field Tran Seq.

How do i achieve the above mentioned results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **ROW_NUMBER()** analytic function:

For example,

**Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (tran_no NUMBER, 
    "DATE" VARCHAR2(10),
     store_id NUMBER, 
     Register_ID NUMBER, 
     Tender varchar2(4));

INSERT ALL 
    INTO t (tran_no, "DATE", store_id, Register_ID, Tender)
         VALUES (01, '23-10-2015', 1000, 001, 'CASH')
    INTO t (tran_no, "DATE", store_id, Register_ID, Tender)
         VALUES (01, '23-10-2015', 1000, 001, 'CRDT')
    INTO t (tran_no, "DATE", store_id, Register_ID, Tender)
         VALUES (02, '23-10-2015', 1000, 001, 'CASH')
    INTO t (tran_no, "DATE", store_id, Register_ID, Tender)
         VALUES (02, '23-10-2015', 1000, 001, 'GIFT')
    INTO t (tran_no, "DATE", store_id, Register_ID, Tender)
         VALUES (02, '23-10-2015', 1000, 001, 'CRDT')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

**Query**

```
SQL> SELECT t.*,
  2    row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY tran_no,
  3                                   "DATE",
  4                                   store_id,
  5                                   register_id
  6                      ORDER BY tender) - 1 tran_seq
  7  FROM t;

   TRAN_NO DATE         STORE_ID REGISTER_ID TEND   TRAN_SEQ
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ---- ----------
         1 23-10-2015       1000           1 CASH          0
         1 23-10-2015       1000           1 CRDT          1
         2 23-10-2015       1000           1 CASH          0
         2 23-10-2015       1000           1 CRDT          1
         2 23-10-2015       1000           1 GIFT          2

SQL>
```

**Note** :

1. You cannot have a space between column names. I have used underscore instead.
2. You cannot used Oracle keywords. If you want to use, then you need to use double-quotation marks. For example, "DATE" column. remember, you need to use the double-quotation marks everywhere you make the reference.

From documentation on [Database Object Naming Rules](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129):

> A quoted identifier begins and ends with double quotation marks ("). If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you must use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.

**UPDATE**

OP wants to update the new column with the sequence generated. You could use **MERGE** statement.

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE t ADD tran_seq NUMBER;

Table altered.

SQL> MERGE INTO t
  2  USING(
  3  SELECT TRAN_NO, "DATE", STORE_ID, REGISTER_ID, TENDER,
  4    row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY tran_no,
  5                                   "DATE",
  6                                   store_id,
  7                                   register_id
  8                      ORDER BY tender) - 1 tran_seq
  9  FROM t
 10  ) s
 11  ON (t.tran_no = s.tran_no
 12      AND t."DATE" = s."DATE"
 13      AND t.store_id = s.store_id
 14      AND t.register_id = s.register_id
 15      AND t.tender = s.tender
 16      )
 17  WHEN MATCHED THEN
 18     UPDATE SET t.tran_seq = s.tran_seq
 19  /

5 rows merged.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY tran_no, tran_seq;

   TRAN_NO DATE         STORE_ID REGISTER_ID TEND   TRAN_SEQ
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ---- ----------
         1 23-10-2015       1000           1 CASH          0
         1 23-10-2015       1000           1 CRDT          1
         2 23-10-2015       1000           1 CASH          0
         2 23-10-2015       1000           1 CRDT          1
         2 23-10-2015       1000           1 GIFT          2
```

Comment: I need to insert these sequence number into the column. 
how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number with partition by clause

```
select tran_no,date,store_id,register_id,tender, row_number() over(partition             
by tran_no,date,store_id,register_id order by tran_no)-1 tran_seq
from table_name
```

Comment: There's this new column in the database in which I need to fill the values.
how do I do that ?

Comment: For that please use merge command. if u need i will post some code.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: I realized it lately after posting this answer that mine solution will work on `MSSQLServer`. So check *@Lalit's* answer for `Oracle`.

Hi you would need to write a script to do that, as this has many steps.

1. You need to create a temp table where you will store transit result like below.

To clean off table if it exist already..

> ```
> IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##abc') IS NOT NULL 
> DROP TABLE ##abc
> ```

Now create a temp table with following query..

> ```
> Declare @sql as nvarchar(max)
> set @sql = N'select * into ##abc from (SELECT t.*,
>       row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY [Tran No],
>                                      DATE,
>                                      [Store ID],
>                                      [Register ID]
>                         ORDER BY Tender) - 1 tran_seq
>     FROM #temp t) as T'
>
> EXECUTE  sp_executesql @sql
> ```

You may check this table, if created.

> select * from ##abc

2. Now drop your existing table

> drop table YourTableName

3. Now just recreate same from temp table.

> select * into YourTableName from (select * from ##abc) as T

4. It's done. You may query your original table now.

> select * from YourTableName

Comment: @LalitKumarB I realized it lately after working on this solution, and I didn't delete this answer intentionally. I just want to keep it here so that if it can help to any other user.. I have update my ans with a NOTE. Thanks for your attention, pls. I